# Unauthorized 401 Error on POST request to Express server only in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, express

I am making a basic POST request to an endpoint on my NodeJS express server, which works perfectly fine in all browsers, including chrome. However, Edge continues to give a random "Unauthorized" 401 Error.

This doesn't make sense because it is a relative endpoint on my own express server.

```
  import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

  ...

  return await fetch("/api/my-endpoint", {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    mode: "cors",
    method: "POST",
    body
  });
```

What could be the reason for this only in edge?

Comment: My guess would be that you need to add `credentials: include` to the `fetch()` options so that cookies will be included with the request which is presumably what is being used for authorization unless there are credentials in the body you are sending.  This feature has been a moving target in browser implementations so it is not surprising that some browsers require it and some do not.

Comment: Also, there doesn't seem to be any reason for `mode: "cors"` since you're using a domain relative URL which must be the same origin.  That will probably not cause a problem, but seems odd to use.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks! Including `credentials: "include"` actually worked for me. Also there's a post regarding this issue: https://engineering.vena.io/2019/05/14/edge-fetch/